# Can I "program" TeX using C/C++?

Tags: programming

I have a fairly complicated TeX programming (not typesetting) task, and I've skimmed [the manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/TeX-programming-notes.pdf) on TeX programming. However, TeX's... clunky programming syntax is less than ideal, and I'm wondering if I can achieve the same result in C (or even Pascal).

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use Lua with LuaLaTeX/LuaTeX ...

Comment: I'm fond of using C++ to create LaTeX code for \input into a larger document.  (See http://www.elfsoft2000.com/worksheets/index.htm for example documents).

Comment: There is a perltex package which may get you closer to a syntax you may find familiar...

Comment: your question isn't at all clear and the answer depends on what you mean by "programming" There is no particular connection between tex and C but you can of course generate the tex code in C++ or any other programming language, either specific fragments or the entire document.  The manual you link to isn't a manual on tex programming, just notes on _quirks_ of tex programming when using a specific function plotting package (pgfplots) so it probably has given you a distorted view of tex. If you gave an indication of what you want to do perhaps someone could offer more specific advice

Comment: It is indeed possible to run compiled C code inside TeX: [avremu](https://ctan.org/pkg/avremu). I never tried it myself though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to insert C++ code into LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/225047/is-it-possible-to-insert-c-code-into-latex)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about C/C++, and I tried [PerlTeX](http://ctan.org/pkg/PerlTeX) (a while ago), which implies an interaction with an external Perl interpreter; but with LuaTeX you may use TeX without TeX, only with Lua, as advertised in the [Lua Wiki](http://wiki.luatex.org/index.php/TeX_without_TeX), with an example.

Hope this helps, even if very late...

Answer (score 1):

> TeX's clunky programming syntax is less than ideal, and I'm wondering if I can achieve the same result in C (or even Pascal).

My [`functional`](https://ctan.org/pkg/functional) package could be your another choice. It provides features similar to other programming languages such as `C`, `Pascal` or `Lua`:

1. It is based on `expl3`, which contains lots of useful functions for programming.
2. The evaluation of composite functions is from inside to outside, which is more intuitive to most users.
3. You can make every function become a group, which will reset local variables after them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{functional}

\begin{document}

\IgnoreSpacesOn
\PrgNewFunction \MathSquare { m } {
  \IntSet \lTmpaInt { \IntEval {#1 * #1} }
  \Result { \Value \lTmpaInt }
}
\IgnoreSpacesOff
\MathSquare{5}
\MathSquare{\MathSquare{5}}

\end{document}
```